# How can I export data without "Save As..."?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, export

I have some data in an xls file. I want to export it to csv. I don't want to save the file as csv, I just want to export it so I don't have to then go back and "Save As..." the original filename (which prompts me to replace).

Is there any way to do this smoothly? I want to keep working in my xls file and occasionally export a copy of the data out to csv. This feature is included in LibreOffice but work uses Excel so I don't want to have to risk reading a file in wrong (by using LibreOffice instead of Excel). In Google Sheets I can just download the data as CSV, very simple.

Using Sheets or Libre won't work because I need to share this file with coworkers. But the export process in Excel is clunky, have to wonder if I'm missing something.

I see an "Import" menu item. But no "Export".

Comment: If you save as the csv, you can then reopen the .xls file. No need to save as again. I don't think excel has an export function that lets you keep the .xls name after a save to a different filename. The only alternative is to make a macro that simply saves twice. Once as .csv and directly after as .xls. This is easily done using the record to macro function.

Comment: Do you mean you want to overwrite the format of xls with the format of csv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you are correct and there is no "export only" and continue function. The best/fastest you can do it and get back to work on the xlsx file:

1. Save the Excel .xlsx file
2. "Save as .csv"
3. Hit CTRL+F4 (to close .csv file)
4. Right-click Excel on the Windows task bar (you will get a list of recently opened Excel files)
5. Hit down-arrow and enter to re-open the second last opened file, i.e. your .xlsx file

Comment: Ugh I probably have to write a VBScript to get an "Export" function. How lame. Not worth the trouble.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this solution, using command line to convert xlsx to csv https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256733/convert-xlsx-file-to-csv-using-batch . Using this you could even make a registry entry so you can right-click any xlsx file and click convert to csv.

Answer (score 1):

Another kludge would be to copy the entire sheet and paste it into an editor (say Atom or Visual Studio Code)

Next (with regular expressions turned on) search and replace globally the tab characters `\t` with the comma character `,`  - then save the file giving it a `.csv` extension.